# Google Url Shortener Url vs Google Analytics views

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, click, google-url-shortener, visitors

Why google url shortener clicks does not converted as views in Google Analytics? Recently, shared some content through shortened URL from facebook pages. We got 500+ clicks (check [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwzijXPhG5Ngb1NMNGtMams2RVU/view?usp=sharing)) but only 50+ views (check [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwzijXPhG5NgbEstb1IwRVAzVWc/view?usp=sharing)) got updated in GA. Is there any possibility to add those numbers to GA?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons this could happen.

1. The URLs are not always redirected to the according URL.

   - Maybe the URL differs if the user has a mobile device?
   - Sometimes the user clicks but never access the website (close before loading the page)
   - Some other reasons the URL differs when redirecting?
2. Your view could be filtered (check filters setting for your GA property: view: filters).
3. Tracking on your landingpage is not working correctly.
4. Clicks happen by users who are not real users (crawlers, bots). So the follow a shortened URL and request the redirect, but don't activate GA tracking.